# Minimum previlage to Renew Microsoft Graph Subscription expiry Date

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We are using webhook to get AD user changes within our system through subscription. For this we have a App registered within Azure AD which has read access to user changes through Graph API .

As webhook subscription expires in 2.5 days we require to renew the subscription through our application.  Can anyone help to let me know what will be the minimum privilege App requires on Graph to renew the webhook as we cannot give lot of access to this app .

Answer (score 0):

App having the consent to ‘User.Read.All’ should be sufficient for creating & updating subscriptions on ‘users’ resource type.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/subscription_update

Is that not working ?

Comment: No it is not working .I have already  User.Read.All privilege to the App but while updating the subscription it is throwing unauthorized exception.

Comment: Could you please give the client request id and time stamp. We will look into that.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Microsoft Graph Doc [here (Permissions Section)](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/subscription_update): *Creating a subscription requires read permission to the resource for which the app will receive notifications* - so, if creating requires it, you can bet that renewing it will too. For instance, if the subscription you want to renew monitors a mailbox, the service needs to have `Mail.Read` permission **IN ADDITION TO** the `Users.Read.All` permission which is required to read the user accounts (for which subscription is an attribute).

Also, some other helpful hints from hours of banging my head against the wall:

1) You also need to be aware that there are two types of permission: Delegated and Application. When I first started using the MS Graph, I always got tripped up on this - so you can [read up here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference) to make sure you understand it and have applied the appropriate permissions.

2) In addition, make sure that your [admin has consented](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service) **AND** if you change any permissions at anytime, **your admin has to re-consent** in order to have the new permissions take effect - i.e. when you update them to have the `Mail.Read` or whatever else. Also remember that when you do this, you are going to want to make sure to **flush your previous auth token caches** to force a refresh so your new token will have the appropriate permissions there as well.